# Connect DbVisualizer to HSQLDB on Mac

Tags: macos, hsqldb, dbvisualizer

I need to connect DbVisualizer to HSQLDB. I've installed both on my mac (OSX 10.6.9). I've installed DbVisualized 8.0.5, and HSQLDB. I have both open, but when I try to ping the server, I receive the error message: `"Cannot connect to 'localhost' on port 9001."` The message below shows up in the Connection Message window:

An error occurred while establishing the connection:

> Long Message:
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>
> Details:
>
> Type: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException
>
> Error Code: -1301
>
> SQL State: 08001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you run the HSQLDB Server, it shows some messages in the window. The last maessage should indicate susseful startup.

```
[Server@80fa6f]: 2011-11-12 21:03:24.904 HSQLDB server 2.2.6 is online on port 9001
[Server@80fa6f]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
```

When you ping from DbVis, the server rejects the data because it's not valid data for making a connection. It shows an exception. This is normal behaviour. On the DBVis side, it should return success after the ping.

You should then connect from DbVis and it should work.

You must use the same HSQLDB jar on both DbVis and HSQLDB (you probably have done this).

You can also double check by executing the HSQLDB (version 2.2.x) jar, which brings up its own database manager and allows you to connect to the server.

One likely cause is network problems. You can try the IP address 127.0.0.1 instead of 'localhost'

Comment: Hi Fred - Thanks so much for getting back to me. I have to admit, I'm completely clueless in this domain. Any chance you could provide more explicit instructions on how to go about doing these tests? I tried changing the hostname in DbVis to the IP Address, but with no success. Thanks again.

Comment: DbVis uses a wizard for selecting HSQLDB Server, loading the jar and specifying the connection, with correct default connection port etc. You just need to specify the login (user) "SA" and an empty password to connect. Other than that, I don't know. Not a Mac user and don't know about its networking intricacies. If all fails, try connecting to HSQLDB Embedded in the wizard (this is an alternative which does not use a server).

Comment: For step by step instructions with images, go to http://hsqldb.org and click on "How To" on the menu and check some of the links there.

Comment: Fred - I forgot to mention, our prof also told us to run runWebServer.bat, in the bin folder of hsqld. Because I have a mac, though, I can't run a bat file. Any way to do this step on a mac?

Comment: It's better to use Server than WebServer, as the first one is more commonly used and there is no difference in functionality. The HSQLDB Guide contains instructions for running Server on Unix type OS's such as Mac. See the documentation of the web site.

Comment: Thank you, Fred. I really appreciate all of your help.